How do you translate "the truth sayer"?
For context, this is a playful modifier of a name. It is functioning as an appositive as in "name X, the truth sayer" but Google's translation suggests a participle form captures the intended meaning, namely dicentis veritatis, which I am literally translating as "of saying of truth" instead of sayer of truth. Any help is much appreciated.

Veridicus means 'speaking the truth.' Although it's an adjective, it can easily be understood as a substantive ('the one speaking the truth'/'the truth sayer'). This word is well attested, being used in authors such as Cicero, Catullus, Lucretius, Livy, and Seneca. There's also a somewhat rarer word with identical meaning, veriloquus.
To modify a female individual, the us in both words would need to be changed to a (veridica, veriloqua).

Another rare option would be verax.

@SebastianKoppehel That sounds very suitable for a cognomen and thus perhaps a better fit to the question. (I did like the ones offered here, too. +1.)
